# Xamarin Carousel View: Align current item center when peaking?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, alignment, carousel

I have a Xamarin Carousel view with the PeakAreaInsets set pretty high so that I can see multiple items in the list at once. However I notice that the current item when set to snap, aligns it self more with the top of the page when I would like it to snap to the center of the page. How can I accomplish this?

Here is a snippet of the code in question:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Days}"
                          CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedDay}"
                          VerticalOptions="Center"
                          HorizontalOptions="Center"
                          PeekAreaInsets="300"
                          x:Name="DayCarousel">
                <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout SnapPointsAlignment="Center"
                                       SnapPointsType="Mandatory"
                                       Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout Spacing="0"
                                     Orientation="Vertical"
                                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                                     Margin="30,10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding FormattedDate}"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding TitleText}"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   Style="{StaticResource LabelHeader1Style}"/>
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.SelectDay, Source={x:Reference this}}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Here is about what it looks like now (just a mock up):

[image]

And here is what I would like it to look like:

[image]

Comment: HI, Welcome to SO. Can you add what is the parent view and view after and before CarouselView?

Comment: @Nikhileshwar Thank you! The CarouselView is the only view in the page. It is wrapped in a ContentPage. I will add that to the original post.

Comment: You could put the CarouselView  in a StackLayout and set the `VerticalOptions` as `FillAndExpand` .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Jonathan meant to say the Current Item is not vertically center aligned to the CarouselView. He does not speak of the CarouselView alignment towards its Parent layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up playing around with it for a bit. I'm not sure how its going to look on other phone formats and sizes since I haven't tested that yet. But eventually I found a happy medium after tweaking the `PeakAreaInsets`, and adjusting the `SnapPointsAlignment`. Currently I have it set to `PeakAreaInsets = 350` and `SnapPointsAlignment="Start"`